# pathFor parameters no longer working after Blaze upgrade

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I updated meteor 0.7 to 0.8, iron router 0.6.2 to 0.7.0 and added blaze-layout 0.2.2.

Previously I had pathFor working with two parameters.  Stripped down to the essential parts it looked like this:

```
{{#each users}}                                                                                                                                                                          
   <a href="{{pathFor 'template' _id=this._id fooParam=foo}}">link text</a>
{{/each}}
```

After the updates pathFor only returns the url for the template, nothing is done with the params.  I can also display the variables and everything is displayed correctly:

```
{{#each users}}
   {{this._id}} {{!displayed correctly in browser}}  
   {{foo}}      {{!displayed correctly in browser}}                                                                                                                            
   <a href="{{pathFor 'template' _id=this._id foo_param=foo}}">link text</a>
{{/each}}
```

No change in result if I just try to use the data context with _id set:

```
{{#each users}}                                                                                                                            
   <a href="{{pathFor 'template'}}">link text</a>
{{/each}}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

From the [History.md](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/History.md) at `iron-router` repo:

> {{pathFor}} and {{urlFor}} still work with some api changes:
>
> - {{pathFor 'routeName' params=this query="key=value&key2=value2"    hash="somehash" anotherparam="anothervalue"}}
> - same for {{urlFor}}

From the comments found in the [code](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/lib/client/ui/helpers.js) (lines 41-47):

> ```
>  /**
>  * Example Use:
>  *
>  *  {{pathFor 'items' params=this}}
>  *  {{pathFor 'items' id=5 query="view=all" hash="somehash"}}
>  *  {{pathFor route='items' id=5 query="view=all" hash="somehash"}}
>  */
> ```

In other words your `pathFor` helper would need to look like the following:

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'template' _id=this._id query="foo_param=foo"}}">link text</a>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

fletch is correct in that I fixed the same thing yesterday. See at https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/580#issuecomment-39526280.

For each pathFor I was getting the following error in the browser console:

```
Exception in Meteor UI: TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
at Object.processPathArgs (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron-router.js?a4167ac4d12a73891d8a9b8c57419a347da0ee12:2200:22)
at Object._.extend.pathFor (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron-router.js?a4167ac4d12a73891d8a9b8c57419a347da0ee12:2227:34)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/ui.js?b523ef986d3d39671bcb40319d0df8982acacfe8:2838:23
at Spacebars.call (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?5d478ab1c940b6f5a88f78b8adc81a47f022da77:173:18)
at Spacebars.mustacheImpl (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?5d478ab1c940b6f5a88f78b8adc81a47f022da77:110:25)
at Object.Spacebars.mustache (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?5d478ab1c940b6f5a88f78b8adc81a47f022da77:114:39)
at HTML.A.href (http://localhost:3000/client/views/prayers/template.prayer_item.js?e15ce9378850d2ce553c8c60647642a543534557:58:30)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/htmljs.js?697b0dd0fbdd1f8984dffa3225121a9b7d0b8609:254:14
at callWithNoYieldsAllowed (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?7afb832ce6e6c89421fa70dc066201f16f9b9105:74:5)
at _.extend._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?7afb832ce6e6c89421fa70dc066201f16f9b9105:212:7)
```

I just changed the various {{pathFor 'items' this}} to {{pathFor 'items' params=this}}

Comment: Thanks m2web.  While I see that using {{pathFor 'template' params="Text" }} ->  http://..template/?Text .  Previously variables could be provided in the parameters, these are no longer evaluated.

Comment: Are your changes on a branch I can try?

Comment: Shwaydogg, the repo is https://github.com/m2web/m2smgrpdaily. Take note of the router.js at github.com/m2web/m2smgrpdaily/blob/master/client/helpers/router.js as well as https://github.com/m2web/m2smgrpdaily/blob/master/client/views/prayers/prayer_item.html